# Give an example where $A \subseteq B$ with $A \neq B,$ but $\left\langle A\right\rangle= \left\langle B\right\rangle.$

Tags: group-theory, examples-counterexamples

I read book of Dummit and Foot Abstract algebra. I need some help with the following exercises(2.4).

Let $\left\langle H\right\rangle$ be subgroup of $G$ generated by a subset $H$

> 1. Prove that if $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ then $\left\langle H\right\rangle = H.$
> 2. Prove that if $A$ is a subset of $B$ then $\left\langle A\right\rangle\leq \left\langle B\right\rangle.$ **Give an example where $A \subseteq B$ with $A \neq B,$ but $\left\langle A\right\rangle= \left\langle B\right\rangle.$**

I can prove both statements. But **I cannot give an example** where $A \subseteq B$ with $A \neq B,$ but $\left\langle A\right\rangle= \left\langle B\right\rangle.$

Comment: Suppose we take $G = (\Bbb Z,+)$, $A = \{2\}$, and $B = \{2,6\}$?

Comment: Or just take any non-trivial subgroup and remove the identity, for example.

Comment: Simple example: take $g\in G$, with $g\ne g^{-1}$; then $\{g\}\subsetneq\{g,g^{-1}\}$, but $\langle\{g\}\rangle=\langle\{g,g^{-1}\}\rangle$.

Comment: @Hayden: Why non-trivial? ;-)

Comment: @j.p. haha, true.

Answer (score 1):

To lift this out of the unanswered queue:

> **Problem.** Give an example where $A \subseteq B$ with $A \neq B,$ but $\left\langle A\right\rangle= \left\langle B\right\rangle.$

Suppose $H=\langle A\rangle$. Then for all subsets $C\subseteq H$, we have $H=\langle A\cup C\rangle$. Therefore, so long as $C\not\subseteq A$, we can take $B$ to be $A\cup C$.

For example, if $H=\mathbb{Z}$ then $H=\langle 1\rangle$, so we may take $A=\{1\}$ and then $B$ can be any set which contains $1$, such as:

- $B=\{1, 2\}$
- $B=\{1, -1\}$
- $B=\{1, 0\}$
- $B=\{2k+1\mid k\in\mathbb{Z}\}$