# why $\langle 2\rangle =\langle 2,6 \rangle$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I have some confusion on this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1182883/557708)

**Give an example where $A \subseteq B$ with $A \neq B,$ but $\left\langle A\right\rangle= \left\langle B\right\rangle.$**

> It is written that  if we take $G= ( \mathbb{Z},+)$ , $A=\{2\}$ and  $B=\{2,6\}$
> Then $\langle A \rangle =\langle B \rangle$

**My thinking:**  Here both $A$ and $B$ generating set are different. So $\langle A \rangle \neq\langle B \rangle$

$A=\langle 2\rangle = \{ 2n \mid n \in \mathbb{Z}\}$

$B=\langle  2,6 \rangle =\{ 12n \mid n \in \mathbb{Z}\}$

**My question:** why is it that $\langle 2\rangle =\langle  2,6 \rangle$ ?

Comment: Basically, because $6\in\langle2\rangle$. Its like adding a trivial generator

Comment: If $z\in\langle2,6\rangle$, then $z=2n+6m$ for some $n,m$ in $\mathbb{Z}$. So, you have $z = 2(n+3m)$, thats the same that $z=2k$, for some k in $\mathbb{Z}$. This is $\langle2\rangle$. The same for $z\in\langle2\rangle$, because it can be written as the form $2n+6m$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're wrong on what $B$ is. It is the set generated by both $2$ and $6$ individually. So instead

$$B = \left\{ 2n + 6m \mid n,m \in \Bbb Z \right\}$$

Of course, since a multiple of $6$ is a multiple of $2$ as well, we see $A=B$.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{alignat}{1}
\langle B \rangle &= \left\{ 2n + 6m \mid n,m \in \Bbb Z \right\} \\
&= \left\{ 2(n + 3m) \mid n,m \in \Bbb Z \right\} \\
&= \left\{ 2l\mid l\in \Bbb Z \right\} \\
&=\langle A\rangle
\end{alignat}